# can't add a stylesheet with sass to a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, sprockets, bootstrap-sass

I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem. With these instructions https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#usage Things work ok except when I want to add a new stylesheet.

## application.css.scss

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "custom";
@import "users";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "comments";
@import "animations";
```

## directory structure

```
▾ stylesheets/
    animations.css
    application.css.scss
    classifieds.css.scss
    comments.css.scss
    custom.css.scss
    foo.css.scss
    news.css.scss
    relationships.css.scss
    scaffolds.css.scss
    users.css.scss
```

But if I add foo.css.scss to `/stylesheets/` and add `@import 'foo'` to application.css.scss

I get a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
  (in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)` error

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The error is happening without `@import "bootstrap"`?

Comment: Which version of sass-rails are you using?  See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4151

Comment: @glebm I think the delinquent gem is [sass-rails-source-maps](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps) here's a stacktrace https://gist.github.com/8834018 and I tried removing the gem and things work correctly. It seems to create a list of css files for the project and any deviation from that invalidates the local application.css

Comment: @glebm my `@import "bootstrap";` declaration is inside `custom.css.scss`

Comment: For the issue with sass-rails-source-maps: a demo app would be best. Specify the exact command(s) to run in the demo's github repository to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems `sass` gem [changed](https://github.com/nex3/sass/commit/f9a615c1e3ab0758976b438b3244487b3249c4d7#diff-b0f8b863d960f4372c581a5274e3d7c5R135) number of arguments of Sass::Importers::Base#public_url.

[New](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps/commit/5905de1b3e551131bc07bb3a896814749ba672c0#diff-7cc95e8646cbc1ed884e0340aab2e533R4) version of `sass-rails-source-maps` should resolve this.